# Fabric sudo() captures incorrect output when user initially enters wrong password

Tags: python, sudo, fabric

Consider the following `sudo` call using Fabric:

```
def ls():
    output = sudo('ls /tmp/', user = 'someone', shell = True)
    print "Output:", output
```

Execute this using `fab` and enter a *wrong* password the first time you are prompted by `sudo`. You'll see an error message and `sudo` will ask you for your password again. Enter the correct password the second time. The session looks something like this:

```
$ fab ls
[user@server] Executing task 'ls'
[user@server] sudo: ls /tmp/
[user@server] out: sudo password: 

[user@server] out: Sorry, try again.
[user@server] out: sudo password: 

[user@server] out: hsperfdata_someone

Output: Sorry, try again.

Done.
```

Note how the value of `output` is the first message printed by `sudo` when the wrong password is entered ("Sorry, try again."). It doesn't contain the subsequent correct output ("hsperfdata_someone").

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way to capture output correctly in such cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that is possibly a bug to be reported, but you could look to [this section](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.3/usage/interactivity.html#combining-the-two) for some different combinations to try.

Comment: No luck juggling `pty` and `combine_stderr`. I've raised this as a bug.

Comment: Figured that'd be the case, but worth a shot anyhow. Thanks for reporting this.